# passwd: Authentication token lock busy

Tags: root, chrome, chrome-book, chrome-os, passwd

I'm using `ASUS Chromebook Flip` with `Google Chrome OS 53.0.2773.3.dev`:

```
chronos@localhost / $ cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Chrome OS
ID_LIKE=chromiumos
GOOGLE_CRASH_ID=ChromeOS
BUG_REPORT_URL=https://crbug.com/new
HOME_URL=https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os
ID=chromeos
chronos@localhost / $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
CHROMEOS_ARC_VERSION=2992394
CHROMEOS_AUSERVER=https://tools.google.com/service/update2
CHROMEOS_BOARD_APPID={432FF9F1-4D2E-7E74-6F98-32E56E904BFB}
CHROMEOS_CANARY_APPID={90F229CE-83E2-4FAF-8479-E368A34938B1}
CHROMEOS_DEVSERVER=
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_APPID={432FF9F1-4D2E-7E74-6F98-32E56E904BFB}
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BOARD=veyron_minnie-signed-mp-v3keys
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BRANCH_NUMBER=2
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_NUMBER=8481
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_TYPE=Official Build
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE=53
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_DESCRIPTION=8481.2.0 (Official Build) dev-channel veyron_minnie 
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_NAME=Chrome OS
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_PATCH_NUMBER=0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_TRACK=dev-channel
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=8481.2.0
DEVICETYPE=CHROMEBOOK
GOOGLE_RELEASE=8481.2.0
chronos@localhost / $ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 24 00:01:48 PDT 2016 armv7l ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l) Rockchip (Device Tree) GNU/Linux
chronos@localhost / $
```

I'm trying to change root password and I'm getting following:

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token lock busy
passwd: password unchanged
chronos@localhost / $
```

Any ideas why? and/or how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/209), you need to use `sudo chromeos-setdevpasswd`.

Comment: As I understand it, the command `sudo chromeos-setdevpasswd` allows you to change the password for the `chronos` user account, not for root.  That may be the answer to the OP, but in my case, I really want to set the password for root, not for `chronos`, and I get the error described above.

Comment: @fulv When you power wash to developer mode, there is an option at the bottom of the screen that mentions "write access" (warning: when you set write access, I believe it powerwashes). Click this and you will be prompted to set a password. Then, after you login, press CTRL+ALT+F2 and login as `root` and use the password you set. After logging in as root, run the set password command as described in this answer. Then, press CTRL+ALT+F1 to get back to a regular screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the root filesystem is mounted in read-write mode; if not, run `mount -o remount,rw` and then retry.

For example, I got this error while resetting the *root* password from recovery mode `init=/bin/bash` which already proved viable. After some forum research, it turned out that I just forgot the first step required to store the new password and proceed regular bootup with `exec /sbin/init`.